# SSRS data driven subscription - validate query button disabled

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I am trying to create a data driven subscription in SSRS. When I enter the query the validate button does not become enabled and then the Apply button also does not become enabled. I have all the permission possible on the report and the folder ("Browser, Content Manager, Manage All Subscriptions, My Reports, Publisher, Report Builder, ReportDeveloper"). It works for the administrator but surely you don't need to be an SSRS Admin to create DD subscriptions?

Answer (score 0):

Have you chosen "A shared data source" or "A custom data source"? If you have chosen "A shared data source", the data source needs to already exist and you need to have selected it. If you do not have a shared data source where this data is stored, you need to choose "A custom data source", which will then prompt you to enter a connection string and credentials. Once a valid data source is chosen, the buttons are enabled.